# watchkit rename target - invalid bundle not a watchkit binary

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

in an xcode project having an WatchKit Extension & WatchKit App - Target.
if i rename the target - from e.g: "Sample WatchKit App" & "Sample WatchKit Extension" - wich where the default generated names to e.g. "WatchKit App" & "WatchKit Extensions".

i can compile & sign the binary but on device it says "invalid bundle not a watchkit binary" - after renaming it back to the original names - it works again.

also tried renaming all occurances of "Sample WatchKit App" & "Sample WatchKit Extensions" in the project file - via text editor - builds fine - even uploads fine to itc but does not run on device.

any idea?

regards
helmut

Comment: are you changes target name or product name of targets?

Comment: i renamed the target: http://x87i.imgup.net/Bildschirma8cd.png
and all Values from build settings etc..

Comment: Not change name of target. Try changing product name, may it will works.

Comment: Try with only change product name which you want.

Comment: hmmm renaming target is impossible? - i consider cloning the project for another app - and would like to have the target/product project-less :D - did that wih the today extension - without a problem

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is still relevant, but I run into same problem recently.

After renaming WatchApp and WatchApp Extension target watch app never launch.

My solution:

- Make sure that in your WatchApp -> Build Settings -> User-defined -> IBSC_MODULE is right extension identifier (extension name with underscores).
- **Make sure that all your watch storyboard classes have updated module. Since you changed it (by renaming the extension target). Xcode does not do that automatically.**

This two steps make my WatchApp works after renaming the targets.

Comment: Big thanks for this! For me the problem was with different module names